# Cannot Select Items In List Until After Scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem with an android activity that extends `ListActivity`. It seems like the items in the list cannot be "clicked" until after I've scrolled the list. After you scroll the list a little, the "clicking" works fine. If the list simply is not scrollable (not enough items, etc) then everything works as it.

Since the activity extends `ListActivity` I just override `onListItemClick`:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
   Log.e(TAG, "Click fired");
}
```

The rows in the list are defined by a custom XML, and after reading through virtually all of the posts on here I'm thinking it has to do with focusable elements, but I can't seem to get it to work. As you can see from the list XML below, all the items have `focusable="false"`, but that didn't help.

I've also tried all the options for `android:descentFocusability` -- but none work properly.

This problem is apparent on all versions of Android from Froyo --> ICS

**Edit**

I have determined that this problem goes away if I remove the onScroll listener that is attached to the same list. However, I really need that and I've put logging info inside both `onScroll` and `onScrollStateChanged` and nothing informative shows up (e.g., scrolling isn't being fired either.) Is this a known conflict?

**Layout XML for activity in question:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search Results: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_gravity="left" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
         <TextView android:id="@+id/query_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="context sensitive"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
       </FrameLayout>
       <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="1dip"
        android:background='@color/grey'
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prodcutdb_results_empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingTop='4dip'
    android:text="No results"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom list item XML:** (adding focusable tags to the `LinearLayout` in this XML has no effect)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="4dip"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/list_item_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:textSize="16dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    <view  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/right"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to remove all focusable tags (descendantFocusability as well)both from activity's xml and items' xml.

Comment: That's how it was before I even started looking into the problem, no dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things short -- nothing worked. I added an onClick listener to each one of the custom views.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom list item XML, did you intend for the 3rd tag to be ImageView? I'm not sure if this is what is causing your problem, but if the sdk sees that your XML is not well-formed it may cause issues.

Comment: The third tag is a custom view, basically an image view that cleans up after itself, removing it (so that the items are just text views) does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should put your list in a normal LayoutView (don't use a scrollView) that can appear and make the rest of your layouts disappear and vice versa when needed so the list can have the complete screen for it. that's how it works for me.

EDIT
I use it like this

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/NewsListLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="gone">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. There is no scroll view at all. What I was saying in my previous edit was that when I attached to the list view's onScroll event this problem started cropping up.

Comment: And also -- we're not interested in "having the list be the full screen" -- there is actually important information above/below the list.